# To run node.js in system boot

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I have written an API using node.js. I have deployed it in the production environment. Now i ran the program(server.js) using forever.js, its working fine

But i want my node to run when the system boots itself.

I tried by creating a file in `\etc\init api.conf` with the following content.

```
start on startup    
exec forever start /home/testuser/server.js
```

But when i reboot my system the above isn't running.Please help me solve this.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Finally i tried this:

```
# Source function library.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions


NODE_ENV="production"
PORT="2100"
APP_DIR="/home/testuser/API/"
NODE_APP="server.js"
CONFIG_DIR="$APP_DIR"
PID_DIR="$APP_DIR/pid"
PID_FILE="$PID_DIR/server.pid"
LOG_DIR="/home/testuser/APIlogs/"
LOG_FILE="$LOG_DIR/project-debug.log"
NODE_EXEC=$(which node)

pidFile="$PID_DIR/server.pid" 
logFile="$LOG_DIR/project-debug.log" 

sourceDir=/home/testuser/API
coffeeFile=server.js
scriptId=$sourceDir/$coffeeFile


start() {
    echo "Starting $scriptId"

    # This is found in the library referenced at the top of the script
    start_daemon

    # Start our CoffeeScript app through forever
    # Notice that we change the PATH because on reboot
    # the PATH does not include the path to node.
    # Launching forever or coffee with a full path
    # does not work unless we set the PATH.
    cd $sourceDir
    PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
    forever start /home/testuser/API/server.js

    RETVAL=$?
}

restart() {
    echo -n "Restarting $scriptId"
    /usr/local/bin/forever restart $scriptId
    RETVAL=$?
}

stop() {
    echo -n "Shutting down $scriptId"
    /usr/local/bin/forever stop $scriptId
    RETVAL=$?
}

status() {
    echo -n "Status $scriptId"
    /usr/local/bin/forever list
    RETVAL=$?
}


case "$1" in
    start)
        start
        ;;
    stop)
        stop
        ;;
    status)
        status
        ;;
    restart)
        restart
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage:  {start|stop|status|restart}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
exit $RETVAL
```

When i tried the following command:

`/etc/init.d/API start` it works fine. When i reboot the system it says "NO forever process" running.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/). People [use it with Node](http://howtonode.org/deploying-node-upstart-monit). Forever is good just for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest switching to [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2).

```
$ npm install pm2 -g
$ pm2 start /home/testuser/server.js
$ pm2 list
```

PM2 can generate and configure a startup script to keep PM2 and your processes alive at every server restart.

```
$ pm2 startup ubuntu
```

To save a process list just do:

```
$ pm2 save
```

You check [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-pm2-to-setup-a-node-js-production-environment-on-an-ubuntu-vps) for more information about setting-up pm2 on a Ubuntu server for production.